# pandoc: doc/api/*.html: withBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: macos, pandoc

when I tried to convert to html file to pdf using pandoc in macOS like this:

```
> cd api
> ls
__404error.html     categories.json     generated_locales.g index.html          index.json          main                main_dev            search.html         static-assets
> pandoc -s doc/api/'*.html' -o output.pdf
pandoc: doc/api/*.html: withBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the pandoc version info:

```
> pandoc -v
pandoc 3.1.2
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2023 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `'*.html'`: the quotes prevent your shell from expanding the asterisk, so pandoc looks for a file that's literally named `doc/api/*.html`, which doesn't exist.